# How to handle android HOME button using libgdx

Tags: android, button, libgdx

i`m writing game for android using libgdx. 
And have problem that game controls are near android buttons HOME and BACK.
There is easy way to handle BACK button, but i havent found something for HOME button. All i want - when user accidentally presses HOME button - to handle it and popup dialog if user want to leave game but not to minimize it at once.

Comment: I think the only way to check for home press (from within libgdx) is when pause() is fired. 
pause() is launched in android when the user receives a call or home button is pressed. 
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.html#pause%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle Home button (nor Lock Screen).

Reference: [How to catch Home/Lock Screen button](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=10986#p49480)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might stumble on this, a plausible solution would be to implement the onPause method in your android launcher

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    //do whatever you need to on pause
    super.onPause();
}
```